# How to create a list from subsets of a CSV file

Tags: r, shiny, subset

I want to make a list for a `selectInput` from a CSV file, but from a subset made based on two previous `selectInput`s. This means that on my app:

1. the user chooses a species name from a list

   radioButtons("species", "Which species are you workingwith?",
   list("Caretta caretta"="Cc",
   "Chelonia mydas"="Cm",
   "Dermochelys coriacea"="Dc",
   "Eretmochelys imbricata"="Ei",
   "Lepidochelys kempii"="Lk",
   "Lepidochelys olivacea"="Lo",
   "Natator depressus"="Nd"))
2. the user chooses a nesting area (country) from a list based on the species:

   conditionalPanel(
   condition="input.country_type=='List' & input.species=='Cc'",
   selectInput("country", "Country:",
   choices=subset(NestingArea2, Sp=='Cc')$Country)),

   ```
          conditionalPanel(
            condition="input.country_type=='List' & input.species=='Cm'",
            selectInput("country", "Country:",
                        choices=subset(NestingArea2, Sp=='Cm')$Country)),
          ......
   ```
3. and then the user must choose a RMU from a list, which is different for each "species" and "country". I have tried this and it didn't work:

   selectInput("rmu", "RMU:",
   choices=subset(
   NestingArea2, Sp=='input.species', Country=='input.country')$RMU)

The .csv (NestingArea2) file has 3 columns as follows:   `Sp | Country | RMU`

I could do what I've done on (2), but since there are many countries, I am searching for something easier.

Comment: `Sp=='input.species' & Country=='input.country'`? note the ampersand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a conditionalPanel and selectInput for each country|RMU separately will be very tedious and (coding) error prone. What you are looking for is a [dynamic UI](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#dynamic-ui) where the choices in a selectInput depend on previous choices.

I haven't tested this because I don't have your data but the following should get you most of the way there. Put the two outputs below in server.R. Then put the uiOutputs in ui.R (note: add comma's as needed). Before even doing that however, make sure to read the Shiny documentation on dynamic ui linked above.

#### Put in server.R

```
output$countrySelect <- renderUI({
  countryChoices <- subset(NestingArea2, Sp==input$species)$Country)
  selectInput("country", "Country:", choices=countryChoices)
})

output$rmuSelect <- renderUI({
  rmuChoices <- subset(NestingArea2, Sp==input$species, Country==input$country)$RMU
  selectInput("rmu", "RMU:", choices=rmuChoices)
})
```

#### Put in ui.R

```
uiOutput('countrySelect'),
uiOutput('rmuSelect')
```

Comment: Hello Vincent,

Thank you very much! Actually it worked for the country list, but it is not working for the RMU list. Any idea why can it be?

Comment: I think the code should probably be (i.e., replace the , by a &): subset(NestingArea2, Sp==input$species & Country==input$country)$RMU

Comment: Good morning, I had tried that, but it didn't work (maybe I did smthg wrong...). It works perfectly, thanks!